# How can a 3-byte wide UTF-8 character only use a single UTF-16 code unit?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, utf-16

From this reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#Description

It states that the value of string.length is actually the number of UTF-16 code units, and not the number of characters.

I am apparently naive in assuming that any UTF-8 characters 3 or 4 bytes wide, would have to take up 2 UTF-16 code units. Here is what I mean:

I did a little experimenting with the string: `œ´®†¥¨ˆøπ¬˚∆˙©ƒ∂ßåΩ≈ç√∫˜µ≤ユーザーコードa` which contains a mix of 1, 2, 3 and 4 byte wide characters. I got some surprising results.

Each UTF-16 code unit is 2 bytes wide.  The number of characters in the string is 35.  Taking string.length of the string equals 36, meaning only one of the characters took 2 UTF-16 code units, yet there are several UTF-8 characters that are 3 and 4 bytes wide.

Using the code below, I examined each UTF-8 character, the number of bytes it uses, and the string.length of it.  It was interesting to me that all of the 3-byte UTF-8 characters only used a single UTF-16 code unit.  The only character requiring 2 code units is the 4-byte wide emoticon.

Can someone please explain how this can be?  Thanks!

Code:

```
function iterateCharacters(str) {
  let te = new TextEncoder();
  let totalBytes = 0;
  let totalCodeUnits1 = 0;
  let totalCodeUnits2 = 0;

  let arr = [...str];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let bytes = te.encode(arr[i]).length;
    let length = arr[i].length;
    totalBytes += bytes;
    console.log("    i: " + i + "    char: " + arr[i] + "    bytes: " + bytes + "    length: " + length);
    // Erroneous assumption that more than 2 utf8 bytes would occupy 2 UTF-16 code units:
    totalCodeUnits1 += bytes < 3 ? 1 : 2;
    totalCodeUnits2 += length;
  }
  console.log("    total UTF-16 code units (erroneous calculation):  " + totalCodeUnits1)
  console.log("    total UTF-16 code units (correct calculation):    " + totalCodeUnits2)
  console.log("    total characters:                                 " + arr.length)
  console.log("    total UTF-8 bytes:                                " + totalBytes)
}

var sample = "œ´®†¥¨ˆøπ¬˚∆˙©ƒ∂ßåΩ≈ç√∫˜µ≤ユーザーコードa";

iterateCharacters(sample);
console.log("total number of UTF-16 code units:  " + sample.length);
console.log("total number of characters:         " + [...sample].length);
console.log("total number of UTF-8 bytes:        " + (new TextEncoder().encode(sample)).length);
```

The results:

```
    i: 0    char:     bytes: 4    length: 2
    i: 1    char: œ    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 2    char: ´    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 3    char: ®    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 4    char: †    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 5    char: ¥    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 6    char: ¨    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 7    char: ˆ    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 8    char: ø    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 9    char: π    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 10    char: ¬    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 11    char: ˚    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 12    char: ∆    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 13    char: ˙    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 14    char: ©    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 15    char: ƒ    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 16    char: ∂    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 17    char: ß    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 18    char: å    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 19    char: Ω    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 20    char: ≈    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 21    char: ç    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 22    char: √    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 23    char: ∫    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 24    char: ˜    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 25    char: µ    bytes: 2    length: 1
    i: 26    char: ≤    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 27    char: ユ    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 28    char: ー    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 29    char: ザ    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 30    char: ー    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 31    char: コ    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 32    char: ー    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 33    char: ド    bytes: 3    length: 1
    i: 34    char: a    bytes: 1    length: 1
    total UTF-16 code units (erroneous calculation):  50
    total UTF-16 code units (correct calculation):    36
    total characters:                                 35
    total UTF-8 bytes:                                85
total number of UTF-16 code units:  36
total number of characters:         35
total number of UTF-8 bytes:        85
```

(See also Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Allasso/o5zpmrc9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-16 is different than UTF-8. All Unicode characters below 00010000 (hex) can be represented in a single UTF-16 character. Above that, you spill over into 2 UTF-16 characters. What that means however is that all 3-byte UTF-8 encodings fit in a single UTF-16 character.

Keep in mind that the 3 bytes of a UTF-8 character are not completely devoted to the actual code point (number). Some of the bits are taken up with "marker" bits that indicate to the interpreting software that a code sequence has started. Same goes for UTF-16, but the scheme (the marker bit pattern) is different.

Comment: So then does Javascript take a UTF-8 string and immediately convert it to a UTF-16 string and store it?  And if so, apparently it converts it back to UTF-8 when the string is accessed? (and how does it know to do that?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's pretty common for languages of that generation to use UTF-16. The process of getting external data into a JavaScript string involves interpreting the UTF-8 sequences and forming UTF-16 code values. What happens when a string "leaves" JavaScript (for example, when updating the DOM) is a problem for the DOM API (or other similar API, like a database connector from Node).

Comment: Apparently however, Javascript must do some tracking of its own and covert it back to UTF-8 when it is retrieved, no? eg, string = "コ";  (new TextEncoder().encode(string)).length) will show it is 3 bytes, indicating it is UTF-8.

Comment: `TextEncoder.encode()` does that. It's just code that performs the transformation of the UTF-16 sequence to a UTF-8 sequence (as a UInt8 typed array).

Comment: So when I dump strings to the console or terminal emulator, the strings get dumped as UTF-16, and the conversion is handled on the console or terminal end?

Comment: No, the browser does it. So in the innards of however `console.log()` is implemented, the browser has to do something like what `TextEncoder.encode()` does to turn the string in to the appropriate character encoding (probably UTF-8 but I'm not sure what happens if the page is using some other encoding)

Comment: It's a little easier to understand in the context of Java, which is also a UTF-16 language. All the Java APIs explicitly expose the "boundaries" between encodings, on the way *in* to a program and on the way *out*.  But JavaScript is still essentially the same story.

Comment: From this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#DescriptionIt states that the value of string.length is actually the number of UTF-16 code units, and not the number of characters.

From this I infer that the disk space in bytes would simply be string.length * 2. Is my assumption is correct?

Comment: Or maybe I should say size of the string rather than disk space.

Comment: That is correct, yes, though bear in mind that when you *do* have 2-code-unit UTF-16 characters, they'll "work" in that you can (for example) add the text to the DOM, but JavaScript provides no native facilities for recognizing them. A 2-unit (32-bit) code is still treated as 2 "characters" as far as `.length` is concerned.

Comment: Right, so if one really wanted to know how many characters a string has, they would need to cast it to a character array, eg [...str].length.

Comment: Well you'd need to go through the string character by character checking (via `.charCodeAt()`) for the UTF-16 2-code-point marker bits, and account for that.